Network Multiplayer with PaperZD
I am using PaperZD with UE 5.4 to make a 2d networked multiplayer game.
If Client 1 moves the animation plays, the direction is set properly, and the character moves.
However, on Client 2's screen the Client 1's facing is set and they move correctly, but no animation is played.
I am using a FVector for the velocity and facing, both are being replicated across the network.  Facing seems to work fine for setting the direction of the animation state, but even though velocity updates the animations state fail to transition.  I even tried doing the check on the server side and just sending out a bool on whether the animation should be played or not.  I can't find any information on using PaperZD with network games, but it looks like it should work.  Any help would be great, I can share whatever segments of the project might help.

What I had to do to fix it was to create a custom event with Run on Server replication every time I wanted to change a variable that changes animations
sets on server
I don't know if it's really correct or efficient but everything that don't work on server but works on client I'm just using this and it works fine, I had a dash using LaunchCharacter that I did the same thing. I don't understand Multicast yet tho
